# Peering a ScyllaDB cluster with one in GKE

Tags: scylla, vpc-peering

I have a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) that I need to peer with one on ScyllaDB. I made the peer request on GCP (using the CLI command Scylla provided), but connecting in the opposite direction is giving me problems. I know my project name and my VPC Network Name (`default`), but apparently I'm using the wrong CIDR because every time I try to submit that request, I get a complaint of the format:

**Unexpected error occurred when creating a VPC peering connection. Please contact support.**
trace-id: [alphanumeric tag]

What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm using the internal IP range of my VPC network as a CIDR. If that's not right, how do I look up the right range?

Comment: Are you using Scylla Cloud?

1. You can file a ZD ticket via the Cloud UI -> Support

2. Have you checked this doc? https://cloud.docs.scylladb.com/stable/cloud-setup/GCP/gcp-vpc-peering

Comment: Yes, I'm using Scylla Cloud. I did file a ticket but they're slow to respond and I'm not sure if the problem is with Scylla or GCP, so I'm trying to figure on my own. Has anyone here succeeded at peering ScyllaDB with GCP?

Comment: Off course, there are multiple Scylla Cloud on GCP customers.
I'm sorry, I searched for a ticket in our Scylla Cloud ZD system and couldn't find one.
Please file a ticket using Scylla Cloud UI --> Support. I also tried to locate your user in our backoffice, but couldn't find it.